# Endless C++ debugging in VS Code

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb

I'm trying to debug simple C++ code in VS Code using gdb but something goes wrong. Gdb debugging session is endless with no errors

Envs:

- Win10 19043.1288 (21H1), Russian language by default
- VS Code 1.60.1
- C/C++ extension 1.7.1
- MinGW installed from msys2-x86_64-20210725
- gcc (11.2.0) and gdb (11.1) are in path

helloworld.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};

    for (const string& word : msg)
    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

tasks.json (note `"-static-libstdc++"` without which resulting .exe file doesn't work)

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe сборка активного файла",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-static-libstdc++"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "компилятор: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Сборка и отладка активного файла",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "logging": { "engineLogging": true },
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Включить автоматическое форматирование для gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe сборка активного файла"
        }
    ]
}
```

Building always passes correctly. But after building debugger freezes

terminal:

```
(base) PS C:\Users\NAME\Documents\Ящик\Разработка\CPP_training\helloworld>  & 'c:\Users\NAME\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.7.1\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe'
'--stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-xrq1w4ni.vpd' '--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-hz0moxmf.ebp' '--stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-ow1iwyo5.0ow'
'--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-iwvvrfdm.b4e' '--dbgExe=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gdb.exe' '--interpreter=mi'
```

debugger console log:

```
1: (342) Wait for connection completion.
1: (869) ->=thread-group-added,id="i1"
1: (871) ->~"GNU gdb (GDB) 11.1\n"
1: (872) ->~"Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.\n"
1: (872) ->~"License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>\nThis is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.\nThere is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law."
1: (873) ->~"\nType \"show copying\" and \"show warranty\" for details.\n"
1: (875) ->~"This GDB was configured as \"x86_64-w64-mingw32\".\n"
1: (877) ->~"Type \"show configuration\" for configuration details.\n"
1: (877) ->~"For bug reporting instructions, please see:\n"
1: (878) ->~"<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.\n"
1: (878) ->~"Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:\n    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>."
1: (879) ->~"\n\n"
1: (879) ->~"For help, type \"help\".\n"
1: (879) ->~"Type \"apropos word\" to search for commands related to \"word\".\n"
1: (885) ->(gdb)
1: (889) <-1001-gdb-set target-async on
1: (901) ->~"Warning: 'set target-async', an alias for the command 'set mi-async', is deprecated.\n"
1: (901) ->~"Use 'set mi-async'.\n\n"
1: (901) ->1001^done
1: (902) ->(gdb)
1: (902) ->&"\n"
1: (902) ->^done
1: (903) ->(gdb)
1: (906) 1001: elapsed time 18
1: (932) <-1002-enable-pretty-printing
1: (947) ->1002^done
1: (948) 1002: elapsed time 15
1: (948) ->(gdb)
1: (948) <-1003-interpreter-exec console "set pagination off"
1: (948) ->&"\n"
1: (948) ->^done
1: (949) ->(gdb)
1: (962) ->=cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off"
1: (963) ->1003^done
1: (963) 1003: elapsed time 15
1: (963) ->(gdb)
1: (963) <-1004-gdb-set auto-solib-add on
1: (963) ->&"\n"
1: (964) ->^done
1: (964) ->(gdb)
1: (978) ->1004^done
1: (979) 1004: elapsed time 15
1: (979) <-1005-gdb-set solib-search-path c:\\Users\\NAME\\Documents\\Ящик\\Разработка\\CPP_training\\helloworld;
1: (979) ->(gdb)
1: (980) ->&"\n"
1: (980) ->^done
1: (980) ->(gdb)
1: (982) ->1005^done
1: (982) 1005: elapsed time 2
1: (982) ->(gdb)
1: (982) <-1006-environment-cd c:\\Users\\NAME\\Documents\\Ящик\\Разработка\\CPP_training\\helloworld
1: (982) ->&"\n"
1: (982) ->^done
1: (983) ->(gdb)
```

Everyting looks like in some github issues and similar stackoverflow questions (like this https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/4523). BUT all of them use C/C++ extension 0.26.0 and pretty old win10 release with some betha features related with unicode. Encoding problem was fixed in C/C++ extension 0.26.1 version, but I use 1.7.1 and have similar symptoms. Maybe I have configured something incorrectly. That's why I'm asking here and not creating new issue in github.

Comment: @AzuxirenLeadGuy Nothing changed (just console started to be external). Adding breakpoint changes nothing to. Debugging freezes before starting - just tiny progress bar running

Answer (score 1):

In your `launch.json` file, try changing these two entries as:

```json
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "externalConsole": true,
```

See if it works.

Comment: Nothing changed